# Is Behringer C-1 mic good enough for foley recordings for the price?

Tags: microphone, foley, sound-effects-recording, purchase-advice, behringer

I have a deadline in three days to finish a project that requires some foley recordings, but I am without a mic. I would buy this mic for this purpose (I am low on budget) and I was wondering if it would do the job? Renting is out of question because that doesn't exist where I live (studio equipment renting).

Answer (score 3):

To be honest any mic can do Foley, I've seen Foley done with an sm57 which is historically an instrument mic. Foley has much more to do with technique than what mic you are using, 80% of Foley is the art and creativity. I have done Foley with an SE1 mic which cost less than £100. As such in an emergency as long as your Foley technique is good, everything is in perfect sync and the materials are suitable then in my opinion any mic will do. Of course great mics make for great Foley but again technique will always triumph over gear.